# How do you fix: "AttributeError: 'Boundary' object has no attribute 'rect'"?

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

I am making a platformer game where there is a boundary in the beginning of the level, so the player can't just keep going to the left for no reason. I decided to make a class called boundary and add it into a list where the rules are you can't pass it. However, I keep getting this error:
"AttributeError: 'Boundary' object has no attribute 'rect'". Can anybody fix this? Also, a better way to do this would also be accepted. Thanks!

```
class Boundary(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.boundary = pygame.Surface([15,600])  
        self.boundary.fill(WHITE)
        self.boundary.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.boundary_rect = 
        self.boundary.get_rect()
        self.boundary_rect.x = -50
        self.boundary_rect.y = 0


class Level01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):
        Level.__init__(self, player)

    level_boundary = [Boundary()]

    for _ in level_boundary:
        boundary = Boundary()
        boundary.player = self.player  
        self.platform_boundary_list.add
                                    (boundary)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def__init__(self):
        super().init()

        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, 
                 self.level.platform_boundary_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right


        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, 
                 self.level.platform_boundary_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            self.change_y = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Haven't ran the code, but the error message seems reasonable. Your `Boundary` class has a property, `boundary_rect` rather than `rect` (which doesn't appear to be directly exposed by pygame's `Sprite` class). Replacing `block.rect` with `block.boundary_rect` should correct this.</s>

**Update:**
Looking through your code, I saw a few issues, with both the `Player` and the `Boundary` classes referring to `rect` properties that did not directly belong their parent, `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. Based on your comments, I decided to rewrite the code into a demo collision test to not only fix the errors but also provide some ideas for how you could consider organizing your code.

The demo is pretty simple; a player and a bunch of random blocks are drawn to the screen. The player block bounces around the edges of the screen, and the colliding blocks are redrawn in a different color. The results look like this:

[image]

Here is the code for the above demo. I added a bunch of comments to clarify what the code does. If anything is unclear, let me know:

```
import random
import pygame
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.surface import Surface

class Block(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__()
        self.idle_color = (255, 255, 255, 255)#white - if not colliding
        self.hit_color = (0, 255, 0, 255)#green - if colliding
        self.image = Surface((rect.w, rect.h))
        self.color = self.idle_color#default
        #Do NOT set color here, decided by collision status!
        self.rect = rect

class Player(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = (255, 0, 0, 255)#red
        self.image = Surface((rect.w, rect.h))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = rect

class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, screen, player, blocks):
        self.color = (20, 20, 20, 255)#gray background
        self.screen = screen
        self.player = player
        self.blocks = blocks

        #hard-coded player x and y speed for bounding around
        self.player_speed_x = 1
        self.player_speed_y = 1

    #Bounces player off the screen edges
    #Simply dummy method - no collisions here!
    def move_player(self):
        p_rect = self.player.rect
        s_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if p_rect.right >= s_rect.right or p_rect.left <= s_rect.left:
            self.player_speed_x *= -1
        if p_rect.top <= s_rect.top or p_rect.bottom >= s_rect.bottom:
            self.player_speed_y *= -1
        p_rect.move_ip(self.player_speed_x, self.player_speed_y)#modifies IN PLACE!

    def handle_collisions(self):
        #First set all blocks to default color
        for block in self.blocks:
            block.color = block.idle_color

        hit_blocks = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.blocks, False)
        for block in hit_blocks:
            block.color = block.hit_color

    #Clear screen with background color, then draw blocks, then draw player on top!
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.color)
        for block in self.blocks:
            #update fill to color decided by handle_collisions function...
            block.image.fill(block.color)
            self.screen.blit(block.image, block.rect)

        self.screen.blit(self.player.image, self.player.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.move_player()
        self.handle_collisions()
        self.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    width = 400
    height = 300
    fps = 60
    title = "Collision Test"
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    #Create a player
    player_size = 20
    player_x = random.randint(0, width - player_size)
    player_y = random.randint(0, height - player_size)
    player_rect = Rect(player_x, player_y, player_size, player_size)
    player = Player(player_rect)

    #Create some random blocks
    blocks = []
    num_blocks = 50
    for i in range(num_blocks):
        block_size = 20
        block_x = random.randint(0, width - block_size)
        block_y = random.randint(0, height - block_size)
        block_rect = Rect(block_x, block_y, block_size, block_size)
        block = Block(block_rect)
        blocks.append(block)

    #Create the level
    level = Level(screen, player, blocks)

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        level.update()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Where should I write this?

Comment: @Blazian444 Have added what the changes would look like.

Comment: @Blazian444 Side question: are all of the `Boundary` objects supposed to have the same `rect` data?

Comment: Nope, but could you still show me how to for future reference?

Comment: @Blazian444 Sure, added an entirely new example that should help clear that up.