# moving a square in a grid

Tags: python-3.x, pygame-surface

making a square move in a grid

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
w = 1008
h = 640
left = 16
top = 16
width = 16
height = 16
YELLOW = (255, 255, 55)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
bg = (255, 255, 255)
x = 0
y = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                top += 16
            if event.key == K_UP:
                top -= 16
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                left += 16
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left -= 16
    x += 16
    y += 16
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 255, 55], [left, top, width, height], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, bg, (w - 16, y), (16, y), 1)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, bg, (x, h - 16), (y, 16), 1)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

at the moment if I # out screen.fill() grid appears on the screen and the rect moves with a tail behind, if I take away the # from the screen.fill() grid disappears but rect moves correct with no tail I want both to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that it isn't doing what you might expect. Every time you iterate through your while loop, you increment the x and y values by 16 and draw a single horizontal and vertical line. This appears to draw a grid, because **the screen is NOT cleared automatically** between your while loop iterations. However, as a result, after a while, **your x and y values increase to the point that you start drawing more and more grid lines that are off the screen** (try to print out the start and end points for these lines in your loop if this is unclear)!

When you add the `screen.fill(BLACK)` call before you start drawing grid lines, you basically clear the entire screen. Since you do not redraw your old grid lines, only the next pair of grid lines are drawn and the rest are lost. Since the new pair of grid lines eventually goes off the screen (as described in the first paragraph), your code does not appear to draw any grid lines.

When you comment out `screen.fill(BLACK)` instead, previous drawings are not cleared. All of the grid is drawn over multiple while loop iterations (in addition to wastefully drawing new grid lines off screen), as is all of the previously positions your player is drawn at.

To solve this, your game drawing loop should be structured like this:

1. Clear the screen.
2. Draw the entire grid, not just two lines at a time. Do this in a function (e.g. `draw_grid`).
3. Draw the rectangle at the new player position. Do this in a function as well (e.g. `draw_player`).
4. Rinse and repeat next iteration!

Implementing these small changes, your code could look like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def draw_grid():
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for y in range(height, h, height):#horizontal lines
        pygame.draw.line(screen, bg, (width, y), (w - width, y), 1)
    for x in range(width, w, width):#vertical lines
        pygame.draw.line(screen, bg, (x, height), (x, h - height), 1)

def draw_player():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 255, 55], [left, top, width, height], 0)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
w = 1008
h = 640
left = 16
top = 16
width = 16
height = 16
YELLOW = (255, 255, 55)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
bg = (255, 255, 255)
x = 0
y = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                top += 16
            if event.key == K_UP:
                top -= 16
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                left += 16
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left -= 16

    draw_grid()
    draw_player()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

That being said, **there is plenty of room for improvement for this code**, which I will leave up to you. The big issue is that you are using a *bunch of global variables*. These are basically all of the variables listed before your while loop. Use of such global variables is "evil" when they are mutable. As your code gets bigger, it will become more difficult to reason what functions are changing these variables, since every function could potentially have access to these variables.

Comment: thanks your great it works, i am new to python, only been coding for 2 weeks more or less still trying to figure out classes which i cant get my head round

Comment: @vapemanjb I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438289/2588654) for another pygame question a few days back which might be useful to get some ideas for how to mix OOP (object oriented programming) with pygame. Good luck learning!